# Input validation and a condition

Tags: c++, validation, conditional-statements

I am having a hard time accepting the users input if they enter something < 60 on the first try. I want to make sure no letters are inputing hence the input validation but also less then a certain number. If the user enters 60 how can I get it to act on the first input?

```
        int score;
        cout << "Enter your test score: ";
        cin >> score;
        while (!(cin >> score)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            cout << "Please enter valid number for the score. ";
        }
        while (score < 60){
            cout << "You failed try again. ";
            cin >> score;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the logic of both your conditions into a single loop:

```cpp
int score;
std::cout << "Enter your test score: ";

// check if either extracting score failed or if score is less than 60:
while(!(std::cin >> score) || score < 60) {
    if(std::cin) { // extraction succeeded but `score` was less than 60
        std::cout << "You failed try again. ";
    } else {       // extraction failed
        // you may want to deal with end of file too:
        //if(std::cin.eof()) throw std::runtime_error("...");
        std::cout << "Please enter valid number for the score. ";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```